# move_base respawning with wrong parameters after crash

Tags: ros, navigation, roslaunch, respawn, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running an instance of `move_base` using `carrot_planner` and `dwa_local_planer`, with global map not initialised. The `move_base` instance is launched with the "respawn" parameter set to true.

The problem is that `move_base` crashes frequently when starting (seems to be a well known problem reported several times elsewhere), but when it is respawned, it does it with incorrect parameters, as if it doesn't re-read the configuration files. Here is an example:

```
core service [/rosout] found
process[move_base-1]: started with pid [30418]
[ INFO] [1417702343.240796462]: Subscribed to Topics: point_cloud_sensor
[ INFO] [1417702343.429482351]: MAP SIZE: 1999, 1999
[ INFO] [1417702343.434297875]: Subscribed to Topics: point_cloud_sensor
move_base: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:69: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = float, int Size = 4, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.
[move_base-1] process has died [pid 30418, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/navigation/move_base/bin/move_base odom:=odometry/imu __name:=move_base __log:=/home/indra/.ros/log/7d3fff28-7bbe-11e4-9961-00f1f31a2be5/move_base-1.log].
log file: /home/indra/.ros/log/7d3fff28-7bbe-11e4-9961-00f1f31a2be5/move_base-1*.log
respawning...
[move_base-1] restarting process
process[move_base-1]: started with pid [30870]
[ INFO] [1417702344.065824161]: Subscribed to Topics: point_cloud_sensor
[ INFO] [1417702344.233580934]: MAP SIZE: 99, 99
[ INFO] [1417702344.237308001]: Subscribed to Topics: point_cloud_sensor
move_base: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:69: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = float, int Size = 4, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.
[move_base-1] process has died [pid 30870, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/navigation/move_base/bin/move_base odom:=odometry/imu __name:=move_base __log:=/home/indra/.ros/log/7d3fff28-7bbe-11e4-9961-00f1f31a2be5/move_base-1.log].
log file: /home/indra/.ros/log/7d3fff28-7bbe-11e4-9961-00f1f31a2be5/move_base-1*.log
respawning...
[move_base-1] restarting process
process[move_base-1]: started with pid [31300]
[ INFO] [1417702344.861728138]: Subscribed to Topics: point_cloud_sensor
[ INFO] [1417702345.035579432]: MAP SIZE: 99, 99
[ INFO] [1417702345.040263928]: Subscribed to Topics: point_cloud_sensor
[ INFO] [1417702345.214279138]: Sim period is set to 0.05
[ WARN] [1417702345.721490201]: The origin for the sensor at (0.06, -0.26, 1.60) is out of map bounds. So, the costmap cannot raytrace for it.
```

As can be seen, when it respawns, the MAP SIZE is 99x99 instead the original 1999x1999. It also gives the error of sensor being out of map, so it's also not getting the configuration for local costmap.

I really need to fix the respawning problem, since it looks like I'm pretty stuck with the buggy version of move_base (older Groovy version, on a 32 bit system).

Any insight will be appreciated.

Thank you and best regards,

**Launch file:**

```
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" name="move_base" output="screen" respawn="true">
    <remap from="odom" to="odometry/imu"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find adam_2dnav)/cfg/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find adam_2dnav)/cfg/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find adam_2dnav)/cfg/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find adam_2dnav)/cfg/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <!-- Carrot planner -->
    <rosparam file="$(find adam_2dnav)/cfg/base_global_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <param name="base_global_planner" value="carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner"/>

    <!-- DWA local planner -->
    <rosparam file="$(find adam_2dnav)/cfg/dwa_local_planner.yaml" command="load" />
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS" />
</node>
```

**Costmap common params:**

```
map_type: "voxel" 

obstacle_range: 7 
raytrace_range: 7 
footprint: [[1.24, 0.735], [1.24, -0.735], [-1.24, 0.735], [-1.24, -0.735]]

inflation_radius: 1

observation_sources: point_cloud_sensor

point_cloud_sensor: {sensor_frame: tf_pmd_camcube, data_type: PointCloud2, topic: cloud_cluster, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

**Global costmap params:**

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  update_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: false # true --> turned to false since no initial map is provided
  width: 200
  height: 200
  resolution: 0.1
  origin_x: -100
  origin_y: -100
```

**Local costmap params:**

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 10
  height: 10
  resolution: 0.1
  origin_x: -5
  origin_y: -5
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198950/move_base-respawning-with-wrong-parameters-after-crash/) by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 329 on 2014-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at your files, I noticed that the resolution is different than the one the map server is emitting (1999 * .05 is about 99 -- this could be the issue). Check your yaml file for the map.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2014-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2014-12-11**:
Actually, there is no initial map ('static_map' set to false), so there is no map yaml file to look at. Anyway, if it was a wrong map yaml file, it would be wrong every time, and not right in the first one an wrong in the respawns.